# CreateDialog[] doesn't return its local variable

Tags: dialog-window

Just trying to build a dialog window for picking items from the list.
However it doesn't work as expected. Here is the simplified example

```
CreateDialog[
 Table[Button["press", DialogReturn[ret = i]], {i, 1, 3}]
 ]
```

then

```
In[10]: ret
Out[10]: i
```

I expected to return the number I clicked.
Could you help me to solve this issue/feature? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work as you expect:

```
CreateDialog[
 Table[With[{i = i}, Button["press", DialogReturn[ret = i]]], {i, 1, 
   3}]]
```

Comment: Oh God. I should probably care more about these specific functions.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: DialogReturn has attribute HoldFirst. That is why With helps here.